# GDAL - Multi-threaded gdalbuildvrt and gdalwarp

Tags: multithreading, gdal, stitch

I need to stich a lot of geotiffs, located on an S3 storage into a big geotif.

Currently I using the following commands

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list filelist.txt -overwrite /tmp/output.vrt
gdalwarp -co COMPRESS=LZW /tmp/output.vrt -overwrite /tmp/result.tif
```

works but painfully slow. we are dealing with around 5-11k geotiffs on S3.
How can i perform this in parallel. CPU and network is neither near a limit so I assume it is running in a kind of "one thread mode".
I saw there is a multi option for gdalwarp but nothing for gdalbuildvrt.

thx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`GDAL` does not naively support concurrency for computing - however you can use multiple threads for compression in some cases. Please refer to [this nice answer on gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241810) and the [relevant documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html).

So you will need to implement the concurrent processing yourself, depending on the framework / software / language / etc. you want to use. Hence, this can't be answered in this context, you'd need to ask a more concise/specific question.

One note: when reading 11k GeoTIFFs from S3, the appropriate format (e.g. [Cloud Optimized Geotiff](https://www.cogeo.org/)) and limiting the number of API calls (e.g. through re-using credentials for threads and processes) can have a huge performance and cost-saving impact.

Answer (score 0):

For speeding up the process ue gdal_translate rather gdalwarp.
Besides, you should implement a tiling system,  create a vrt for each tile , followed by gdal_translate. Then in the end you merge the tile again with vrt + gdal_translate.